# mapper_parsing_exception in ElasticSearch php client

Tags: php, ubuntu, elasticsearch

Error

```
[body] => {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to     parse"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to 
parse","caused_by":{"type":"not_x_content_exception","reason":"Compressor detection can 
only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent ytes"}},"status":400}
```

I'm getting an error while adding the documents to my index.

```
http://localhost:9595/patient_trimester
{
"patient_trimester": {
"aliases": {

},
"mappings": {
  "_default_": {
    "_all": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "string_fields": {
          "mapping": {
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "omit_norms": true,
            "type": "string"
          },
          "match": "*",
          "match_mapping_type": "string"
        }
      }
    ],
    "properties": {
      "@version": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      }
    }
  },
  "patient_trimester": {
    "_all": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "string_fields": {
          "mapping": {
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "omit_norms": true,
            "type": "string"
          },
          "match": "*",
          "match_mapping_type": "string"
        }
      }
    ],
    "properties": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
      },
      "@version": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      },
      "last_consult_by": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      },
      "mpi": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      },
      "bill_id": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "bill_date": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
      },
      "site": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      },
      "effective_edd": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
      },
      "is_converted": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "admitting_physician": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      },
      "days": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "trim": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      },
      "tags": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      }
    }
  }
},
"warmers": {

}
}
}
```

This is how I created the index through postman.

in the $result variable im sending

```
    (
        [last_consult_by] => xxxxxx
        [mpi] => xxxxxxxx
        [bill_id] => 176073
        [bill_date] => 2018-07-12 12:00:00
        [site] => xxx
        [effective_edd] => 2018-07-28 12:00:00
        [is_converted] => 0
        [admitting_physician] => xxxxxxxxx
        [days] => 16
        [trim] => Array
            (
                [trim3] => 1
            )

    )


    $params = [
        'index' => 'patient_trimester',
        'type'  => 'patient_trimester',
        'body'  =>  $result
    ];

    $res = $client->index($params);
    print_r($res); exit;
```

I'm not getting why mapper_parsing_exception is happening.
Is this because of my mapping of datatypes? mapping given for Datatype of effective_edd,bill_date and the trim is right ?
please help me out to resolve this issue.